# Выпадающее меню не ровно под ссылкой

Tags: html, css

Когда навожу курсор на ссылку выпадающее меню оказывается где-то слева, а не прям под ней. Css код ниже

```
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 100vh;
      background: url("background.jpg");
      jpg: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    }

    header {
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.85);
      padding: 20px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0 8%;
    }

    header ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    header li {
      border: 1px 0;
      margin: 5px 0;
    }

    header li a {
      color: black;
      font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      padding: 5px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    header li a:hover {
    background: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.25);
    }

    header a em { 
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font: normal 85% Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 125%; 
    }

    header a span {
    color: #125F15;
    font: normal 70% Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 150%;
    }

    header img {
      height: 100px; /* Уменьшение размера изображения на 50% */
      margin-right: 40px;
    }

    header a {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-right: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    nav ul li ul {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 180px;
      background: #fff;
      display: none;
    }

    nav ul li ul li {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
      display: initial;
    }

    footer {
      background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
      max-width: 1500px;
      color: white;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden; /* Убираем полосу прокрутки по горизонтали */
    }

    footer a {
      color: white; /* Цвет ссылок в футере */
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .copyright {
      float: right;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .preloader {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 9999; /* Установить высокий уровень z-index, чтобы элемент был поверх других элементов */
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    body {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    body.loaded {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .video-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 60vh;
    }

    .marquee {
      background-color: green; /* светло-зеленый цвет фона */
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }

    .marquee span {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
      color: white;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    @keyframes marquee {
      0% {
        left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        left: -100%;
      }
    }

    .modal {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }

    .modal-content {
      background-color: white;
      margin: 15% auto;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #888;
      width: 50%;
      height: 70%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .close {
      color: #aaaaaa;
      float: right;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 0;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #000;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=text], textarea {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin-top: 6px;
      margin-bottom: 16px;
      resize: vertical;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
      background-color: #45a049;
    }

    .container {
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Приведите разметку и нормальные `css` стили.

Comment: Мужик, тут ответы на столько хороши на сколько хороши начальные данные. Просто css код никакой информации практически не дает. html разметку в студию...